# How to search inside a json file?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file with content like so  :

```
[
  {
    "Name": "A+",
    "Type": "Array",
    "Designed by": "Arthur Whitney"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Ada",
    "Type": "Compiled, Imperative, Procedural, Object-oriented class-based",
    "Designed by": "Tucker Taft, Jean Ichbiah"
    }
    {
    "Name": "C",
    "Type": "Compiled, Curly-bracket, Imperative, Procedural",
    "Designed by": "Dennis Ritchie"
  },
  {
    "Name": "C#",
    "Type": "Compiled, Curly-bracket, Iterative, Object-oriented class-based, Reflective, Procedural",
    "Designed by": "Microsoft"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Java",
    "Type": "Compiled, Curly-bracket, Imperative, Object-oriented class-based, Procedural, Reflective",
    "Designed by": "James Gosling, Sun Microsystems"
  },
  {
    "Name": "JavaScript",
    "Type": "Curly-bracket, Interpreted, Reflective, Procedural, Scripting, Interactive mode",
    "Designed by": "Brendan Eich"
  }
  ]
```

I want to write a web application that user type a word FOR EXAMPLE "java" in a textbox and then click the search button  .after that search inside this JSON file and show the result in a web page  .
I am new in a web application.I don't know how to search through a JSON file and represent the result  .Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can JUST do it by JavaScript: load this file to browser, then loop this array and compare the name

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the job done, you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com) and than simply do something like this:

```
var data = [...] // your jsonfile as array of objects
_.findWhere(data, {Name:"Java"}) // returns the object
```